# notepad++ Remove Unnecessary Blank and EOL replace

Tags: notepad

[image: notepad plus plus]

I have over 300 files.
I want to use the "Remove Unnecessary Blank and EOL"  function and correct everything with one click.
Is this possible?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't. Edit commands only act on current file. May be be you can use Find & Replace with regex on all these files. could you show (as text, not image) some example file and expected result?

Comment: I disagree with the closing vote because it's not realistic to open 300 files in Npp.

Comment: Is it unrealistic or impossible? The PC may choke, but you can at least TELL your computer to open 300 files at the same time. And even if OP can only do batches of 30 or 50 at a time, that's still fat better than 300 times.

Comment: Maybe I’m missing something, but the other question doesn’t seem to answer this one, because the other question is about a macro and this one is about a menu action.  This question deserves at least an answer that says how to create a macro that executes a menu action, and then (maybe) links to the other question.

Answer (score 0):

> From [Npp doc](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/editing/):
>
> - Remove Unnecessary Blank and EOL: performs a combined Trim Leading and Trailing Spaces and EOL to Space operation.

As you can't open hundreds of files, here is a way to do the job using `Find in files`:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `\A\h+|\h+\z|(\h*\R+\h*)`
- Replace with: `(?1 )`
- Filters: `Whatever you want`
- Directory: `Path\where\your\files\are`
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace in files</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\A          # beginning of file
\h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
  |           # OR
\h+         # 1 or more horizontal spaces
\z          # end of file
  |           # OR
(           # start group 1
   \h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
   \R+         # 1 or more any kind of linebreak
   \h*         # 0 or more horizontal spaces
)           # end group 1
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1 )       # if group 1 exists, insert a space
```

> Example for one file:

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]